# Variant optional to return error string or value

Tags: c++, error-handling, optional

I needed a class with more information than optionals give, I need to know why the optional is not valid in error states. I used a Boost variant for this. Since this will be wrapping almost all of my return values, I need to know if it's as fast as possible (i.e. did I do move semantics and all that jazz properly?).

```
template<typename T>
class Result
{
public:
    Result(const std::string& errorString) {
        contents = errorString;
    }

    Result(T&& value) {
        contents = std::forward<T>(value);
    }

    operator bool() {
        //is the active value our T
        return contents.which() == 0;
    }

    T unwrap() {
        return boost::get<T>(contents);
    }

    std::string unwrapErr() {
        return boost::get<std::string>(contents);
    }

private:
    boost::variant<T, std::string> contents;
};
```

Example use

```
Result<std::vector<int>> foo()
{
    if(success)
         return Result<std::vector<int>>({1,2,3});
    else
         return Result<std::vector<int>>("failure reason");
}

if(auto vec = foo())
   vec.unwrap() //do stuff to contained value
else
   std::cout << vec.unwrapErr();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said:

> I need to know if it's as fast as possible

The only thing I could think of that would make your program potentially faster is:

**Initialize the member variable using initialization list syntax**

```
Result(const std::string& errorString) : contents(errorString) {}

// boost::variant already has a constructor that takes a rvalue reference.
Result(T&& value) : conents(value) {}
```

#### Other suggestions:

**Add `operator T` functions instead of `unwrap`**

This may be a matter of stylistic preference but I think it is better to use:

```
Result<int> r = <some function call>;
if ( r && r == 10 )
{
    // Do something with r
}
```

than

```
Result<int> r = <some function call>;
if ( r && r.unwrap() == 10 )
{
    // Do something with r
}
```

You can use the former syntactic construct by providing `const` and non-`const` versions of user defined conversion operators.

```
operator T const& () const
{
   return boost::get<T>(contents);
}
operator T& ()
{
   return boost::get<T>(contents);
}
```

**Decide how to deal with use of `Result<std::string>`**

If you use `Result<std::string>`, the function `operator bool` will always return `true`. For that use case, there is no way to tell whether a function returned with success or failure.

One way to deal with the problem will be to prevent use of `Result<std::string>` using `static_assert`.

```
static_assert(std::is_same_type<T, std::string>::value == false,
              "Can't use std::string as template paramete");
```

**Use a better name than `unwrapErr()`**

I would prefer to use something like `getError()` or `getErrorString()`.

#### Update

The `operator T` functions will be problem when `T` is `bool`. If you like to use the `operator T` functions for all types, it will be better to change `operator bool` to a different function, such as `isGood()`.

```
bool isGood() {
    //is the active value our T
    return contents.which() == 0;
}
```

then, you'll have to use

```
Result<int> r = <some function call>;
if ( r.isGood() && r == 10 )
{
    // Do something with r
}
```

Comment: Result(T&& value) : conents(value) {} should use std::forward right? Im most worried about getting move semantics and such correct. I will add T operator, i like that, although im curious what would operator T do when T is bool. Would it call my operator bool or operator T as bool type

Comment: @StephenEckels, Using the `operator T` functions will be a problem with `T` is `bool`.

Comment: I've overloaded the dereference operator instead. And I wrapped the STD string error type in a class. Works well

Answer (score 2):

I have added two suggestions.

1. Create a wrapper for errors, so you can different it from `std::string` and you will be able to use `Result<std::string>` too.

   ```
   struct Err {
     std::string msg;
   };
   ```
2. Use the **dereference operator** to access the content of the `Result` class, as C++ std classes do. It will make the `Result` class work with `bool` too.

   ```
   const T& operator *() const {
       return std::get<T>(contents);
     }

     T& operator *() {
       return std::get<T>(contents);
     }
   ```

   So you can use this way:

   ```
   Result<Foo> result = doSomething();
   Foo resultValue = *result;
   ```

   You can even add the **pointer** operator too!

   ```
     const T* operator ->() const {
       return &std::get<T>(contents);
     }

     T* operator ->() {
       return &std::get<T>(contents);
     }
   ```

Final code and some usages:

```cpp
struct Err {
  explicit Err(std::string s) : msg(std::move(s)) {}
  std::string msg;
};

template<typename T>
class Result
{
public:
  Result(const Err& errorString) : contents(errorString) {
  }

  Result(T&& value) : contents(value) {
  }

  Result<std::string>(const char* v) : contents(v) {} 

  explicit operator bool() const {
    return contents.index() == 0;
  }

  const T& operator *() const {
    return std::get<T>(contents);
  }

  T& operator *() {
    return std::get<T>(contents);
  }

  std::string getErrorMessage() {
    return std::get<Err>(contents).msg;
  }

private:
  std::variant<T, Err> contents;
};
```

Usage:

```cpp
  BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(TestResultClass)
  {
    Result<int> r1(1);
    BOOST_REQUIRE(r1);
    BOOST_REQUIRE(*r1 == 1);
    Result<int> r2(Err{"Erro"});
    BOOST_REQUIRE(!r2);
    BOOST_REQUIRE(r2.getErrorMessage() == "Erro");
    Result<bool> r3(false);
    BOOST_REQUIRE(r3);
    BOOST_REQUIRE(*r3 == false);
    Result<bool> r4(Err{"Erro"});
    BOOST_REQUIRE(!r4);
    BOOST_REQUIRE(r4.getErrorMessage() == "Erro");
    Result<bool> r5(true);
    BOOST_REQUIRE(r5);
    BOOST_REQUIRE(*r5 == true);

    Result<std::string> r6("Sucesso");
    BOOST_REQUIRE(r6);
    BOOST_REQUIRE(*r6 == "Sucesso");
    Result<std::string> r7(Err{"Erro"});
    BOOST_REQUIRE(!r7);
    BOOST_REQUIRE(r7.getErrorMessage() == "Erro");

  }
```

And:

```cpp
Result<bool> foo() {
   if (a-error) {
      return Err{"My error message"};
   }
   
   return bar == 100; //not error return as boolean
}
```

Edit: I have added the `explicit` keyword for the `Err` class, pointed by @G. Sliepen. And I added a specialization to create `Result<std::string>` with `const char*`, so we can just return `const char*` from functions with `Result<std::string>` return type.

Comment: You should make the constructor that takes an `Err` `explicit`, otherwise implicit conversion from a string is possible.

Comment: Thanks @G.Sliepen to point it out. I don't think is there any case that it would be an issue for this case, but it's better with `explicit`.

Answer (score 1):

This obviously isn't suitable for functions that return `std::string`.  We might be able to address that if we access values by index rather than by type.

You should be able to use `std::variant` for this, and not depend on Boost.

`std::forward()` is for *forwarding references*.  But `T&&` here is an *rvalue reference*.  So we're unable to construct from an lvalue:

```
std::vector v = {1,2,3};
return Result<std::vector<int>>{v}; // compile error
```

We should be accepting by value, and using `std::move` to minimise copying:

```
    Result(std::string errorString)
        : contents{std::move(errorString)}
    {}

    Result(T value)
        : contents{std::move(value)}
    {}
```

It's probably worth a comment to mention that implicit conversions are intentionally allowed here, as we'd normally expect single-argument constructors to be `explicit`.

The member functions ought to be `const`, as they do not modify the value.  And the "unwrap" functions can return reference to const, which avoids unnecessary copying:

```
    // True if it contains a T
    operator bool() const;

    const T& unwrap() const;

    const std::string& unwrapErr() const;
```

---

Suggested improved code:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <variant>

template<typename T>
class Result
{
    std::variant<std::string, T> contents;

public:
    Result(std::string errorString)
        : contents{std::move(errorString)}
    {}

    Result(T value)
        : contents{std::move(value)}
    {}

    // True if it contains a T
    explicit operator bool() const {
        return contents.index();
    }

    const T& unwrap() const {
        return std::get<1>(contents);
    }

    const std::string& unwrapErr() const {
        return std::get<0>(contents);
    }
};
```

---

I moved the error string to be the first element of the variant, as this might be a step towards instantiating with more than one type argument (`template<typename... T>`), to avoid wrapping a variant return inside the variant.